# What is the order of precedence for a statement containing the universal quantifier and an implication?

Tags: logic, quantifiers, predicate-logic

In the statement $\forall x:X \bullet p(x) \Rightarrow q(x)$, does the universal quantifier apply over the predicate q?

i.e. it is equivalent to $$\forall x:X \bullet (p(x) \Rightarrow q(x))$$ or does the implication take precedence, i.e. $$(\forall x:X \bullet p(x)) \Rightarrow q(x)$$

Comment: Usually the scope of a quantifier extends as far right as possible, therefore $\forall x.\ p(x) \to q(x)$ would be $\Big(\forall x.\ \big(p(x) \to q(x)\big)\Big)$.

Comment: thanks - did you mean to put the outer parentheses around the entire statement though? Or are you saying that it is equivalent to  the first of my suggestions?

Comment: It is your first suggestion.

Comment: For the sake of everyone's sanity, parenthesize defensively.

Comment: @dtldarek: 
I often read books along the lines: "scope of a quantifier applies to as little as possible". However, your convention ( "scope of a quantifier extends as far right as possible"), makes more sense to me. Can you, please, suggest a book/reference adopting it?

Comment: @antonio First, you have to be aware of the use of the dot in the formula in question (both in the OP and in my comment), only then it is standard to extend the scope as far right as possible. Unfortunately I don't have any of my books at hand (and these were not in English, so probably not so useful here anyway), but a lot of CS-related texts use this convention, especially, because of lambda calculus (see the answer below about "Church dot") and because the scoping in programming languages usually works in this way (or even in math if you think of name/definition introduction). **Cont.**

Comment: **Cont.** However, while I cannot agree that dot usage "is to be deprecated" or that "it isn't clear how to scope it", the convention mentioned by @PeterSmith below is probably more widespread and likely also more comfortable for the readers, thus it is good to be fluent with it (that is, I would recommend to stick with the books you have). Personally I prefer the dots, but when writing a paper your preferences don't matter that much, i.e., you use what the journal/community uses. Sorry if that does not help you much. **Fin.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The non-standard notation used is to be deprecated, exactly because it isn't clear how to scope it.

Suppressing for a moment the restriction on the quantifier, we need to distinguish in standard notation:

> $\forall x(Px \to Qx)$

and

> $(\forall xPx \to Qx)$

The usual convention for dropping outermost brackets would mean that

> $\forall xPx \to Qx$

is allowed slang for the second wff.

Now, there is an alternative old-school system [old-school in standard first-order logic texts, at any rate] for replacing parentheses with dots (as required to fix scope), where we would write instead

> $\forall x.Px \to Qx$

and (again, but now not slang)

> $\forall xPx \to Qx$

But it is bad practice to mix dots and brackets (two different scoping systems), and we shouldn't write your first formula -- dots *and* brackets -- nor the second.

For restricted quantifiers - with $X$ giving the restricted domain - we could in some syntaxes replace $\forall x$ with $(\forall x \in X)$ [or perhaps $(\forall x \colon X)$]  thus:

> $(\forall x \in X)(Px \to Qx)$

vs [dropping outer brackets]

> $(\forall x \in X)Px \to Qx$

A lot of work went into perfecting standard notation from Peano and Russell, through to Hilbert, Church and others: there are good reasons not to deviate!

Comment: Funny you should mention Church; in lambda calculus/type theory, one invariably sees $\lambda x. x$ or $\lambda x:X. x$, with (as dtldarek mentions in a comment) the scope extending as far to the right as possible.  When working with dependent types, notation is more varied, but you're still far more likely to see $\forall a : A. a = a$ than one of the parenthesized notations.  For what it's worth, I'd read $\forall x P x \to Q x$ the same as $\forall x. P x \to Q x$, and would require $(\forall x. P x) \to Q x$ for the other interpretation.

Comment: Yes -- Church dots (originally from *Principia*) live on in the lambda calculus! But I think you'll find that in any standard logic text, the wff $\forall xPx \to Qx$ counts as having the variable in $Px$ bound and the variable in $Qx$ free.

Comment: It seems there is a disagreement between you and dtldarek, then?

Comment: so in the syntax with dots, ∀x.Px→Qx is equivalent to ∀x(Px→Qx)?

Comment: @PeterSmith: Fair enough—I study programming languages, and my mathematical logic class was a while ago, so I will gladly defer here!  (In fact, I pulled up Enderton, which we used in that class, and confirmed what you said, so I must have known this once.)  I mostly found your characterization of the dots as "old-fashioned" surprising (but forgot to actually mention that in my comment), since in my field it's all I see; I sometimes forget how much variation there is in notation, even for such basic things.

Comment: @RichAshworth Yes (methinks!)

Comment: @AntalS-Z Yes, I should have said (and now have corrected the answer to say) old-school as far as standard FOL is concerned.

Comment: @PeterSmith why doesn't everybody use polish notation, then all those problems melt as snow in the sun

Comment: I think you meant to write the second wff as (∀xPx) → Qx, since disambiguating (∀xPx → Qx) requires presupposing the convention that you are trying to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but I was intrigued by the "Church Dot" and as I have "A Formulation of the Simple Theory of Types" *(Alonzo Church, The Journal of Symbolic Logic, Vol. 5, No. 2. (Jun., 1940), pp. 56-68.)* right here, I thought I would do a quick screengrab of his description of the "Dot" in question.

[image: Dot Notation explained in "A Formulation of the Simple Theory of Types"]